# Can I install DOS as a lui frontend bootloader?

Tags: bootloader, disk-operating-system

Hi I was wondering if it's possible to install DOS as a lui frontend bootloader?

For example, let's say I have Windows XP, Windows 7, and Ubuntu linux all installed, I want to have my computer boot into DOS where I'll then be able to boot into any of the aforementioned O/S via the prompt.

If this is possible, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the grub bootloader from dos using this [Grub4dos](http://grub4dos.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Grub4dos_tutorial) tutorial.